# How to fetch the BAYC NFT Price from chailnlink or any other method?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereumjs, oracles, chainlink

I want to fetch BAYC NFT price using oracle. I have checked chainlink but didn't found any solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the BAYC NFT price you can build & use any kind of [Chainlink Any API](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/) request. You could use any API like coingecko to grab the price into your contract.

For example, we could pull from here:

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bayc-vault-nftx
```

If you want the price in USD, for example, you can construct it like this:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol';
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol';

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    uint256 public price;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    event RequestPrice(bytes32 indexed requestId, uint256 price);

    /**
     * @notice Initialize the link token and target oracle
     *
     * Rinkeby Testnet details:
     * Link Token: 0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709
     * Oracle: 0xf3FBB7f3391F62C8fe53f89B41dFC8159EE9653f (Chainlink DevRel)
     * jobId: ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb
     *
     */
    constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
        setChainlinkToken(0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709);
        setChainlinkOracle(0xf3FBB7f3391F62C8fe53f89B41dFC8159EE9653f);
        jobId = 'ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb';
        fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10; // 0,1 * 10**18 (Varies by network and job)
    }

    function requestBaycPrice() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        req.add('get', 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bayc-vault-nftx');

        // request.add("path", "market_data.current_price.usd"); // Chainlink nodes prior to 1.0.0 support this format
        req.add('path', 'market_data,current_price,usd'); // Chainlink nodes 1.0.0 and later support this format

        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int256 timesAmount = 10**18;
        req.addInt('times', timesAmount);

        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
    }

    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _price) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        emit RequestPrice(_requestId, _price);
        price = _price;
    }

    /**
     * Allow withdrawal of Link tokens from the contract
     */
    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))), 'Unable to transfer');
    }
}
```

You'd have to change the oracle address and jobId depending on the chain and node you use.

This would be an example of pulling from a single API, through a single node. In order to make this decentralized, you'd have to pull many APIs through many different nodes. So the example above shows the building block of how to do it.

Comment: any refrence on how to pull many APIs through many different nodes ?

Answer (score 0):

[tellor](https://www.tellor.io) can help with it.

They can do any kind of data.  You can either try and implement it yourself (here's an example: https://github.com/tellor-io/sampleUsingTellor )

or you can fill out a github issue and they'll help you out:  https://github.com/tellor-io/dataSpecs/issues/25